# How to install Ubuntu with only the required driver for my hardware

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-minimal

With the Ubuntu minimal CD, I remember in the past that I was able to install Ubuntu with only the required drivers for my hardware, but I can't find it anymore.

Did I was dreaming?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were dreaming, or maybe you read something about compiling a custom kernel, which gives you thousands of options of what you may include or exclude.

This is Ubuntu's documentation for compiling your own kernel: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

The problem with this is you'll be solely responsible for its stability and maintenance; it will not be an official Ubuntu-provided kernel - and it's a fair bit of work.  You don't get much gain in terms of disk space, and you lose a lot in terms of incompatibility with certain hardware.

Ubuntu does provide some different flavours of pre-built kernel.  Where the normal one is `linux-image-generic` one other they provide is `linux-image-virtual` which has a much reduced set of device drivers, intended for running as a guest in a VM (the drivers included should provide support across the major platforms: Qemu/KVM, Xen, etc).